# "If" statement seems to behave erratically in my code

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm just learning Python and decided to try a bit of code resembling the old Milton Bradley 'Simon' game.  Which is a memory sequence game with four colored buttons.  I'm using numbers 1-4.  I'm stuck at the moment where the 'if' statement decides if the my answer is correct or not.  I've run this through quite a few time and I can't figure out why it jumps to the you LOSE when the answer is correct.  For example:

```
Start game?: Y 
[4, 1, 4, 2, 4] 
Pick: 4 
Pick: 1
Pick: 4
Pick: 2
you LOSE
Pick: 4

Process finished with exit code 0

import random
START=input('Start game?: ')
length_of_game=5
Simon_List=[] 
if START == 'Y':
    i=0
    while i<length_of_game:
        i += 1
        number=random.randint(1,4)
        Simon_List.append (number)
    print (Simon_List)    
    for x in Simon_List:
        #print (x)
        Your_guess=int(input('Pick: '))
        if Your_guess == Simon_List[x]:
            break
    print('you LOSE')
```

Comment: But why after the fourth question?  Should that not have occurred first?

Comment: Consider the fourth iteration. What are the values of `x`, `Your_guess`, and `Simon_List[x]`?

Answer (score 0):

`Simon_List[x]` isn't doing what you think its doing, its using the value at each element in the list and then you're using that to look up a value in the list at that given index (so the first iteration would be looking up the value at index 4 in the example), you just need to compare vs `x`

```
if Your_guess == x:
```

Comment: That's it!  Thanks!